# Returning the string after manipulating html by DOMDocument

Tags: php, wordpress, domdocument

I have a wordpress page in which i have to replace the image tag the user has placed is the wordpress editor with the featured image he choose in wordpress admin.

What I've done as yet i took the full page content and replaced the image tag src attribute. But i am not getting the way to return the manipulated html to $page->post_content so that i see the desired result on my page. Here is the code i have done so far.

```
        // Calling about page
        if($page->ID == 7){
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(7), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            @$dom->loadHTML($page->post_content);
            $imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");
            foreach($imgs as $img){
                $img->setAttribute( 'src' , $image[0] );
            }
        }
        echo $page->post_content; //It is still showing the old image.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter `post_content` with `content_save_pre`

as

```
function replace_content_image($page)
    {
       if($page->ID == 7){
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(7), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
              $dom = new DOMDocument();
              @$dom->loadHTML($page->post_content);
              $imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");
              foreach($imgs as $img){
                 $img->setAttribute( 'src' , $image[0] );
              }
               return $page->post_content;
   }    
add_filter( 'the_content', 'replace_content_image');
```

may this help you

Comment: I've done this by `$page->post_content = $dom->saveHTML();` but your answer provide me a good approach of using filters rather than doing it all on index.php page. Thanks :)

Comment: Is content_save_pre correct. I want this happen on page rendering not saving. ?

Comment: I think this is wrong filter its not effecting the output.

Comment: then give a try to only by `the_content` filter

Comment: did this. Not worked. I think in the_content filter we cannot $page directly ? we have to get_the_content for each pages ?